# ignore special characters in title (xslt)

Tags: xslt

my xslt:

```
<a href="?Filter={$itleUrl}"><xsl:value-of select="@Title" /></a>
```

I get this output if the title is P&O:
P&O

but what i realy want is that he ignores the special characters, because the filter thinks it's a extra value. Is this possible? I already tried disable-output-escaping but nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

If the value `$itleUrl` comes from a Hyperlink column use the XSLT `OuterTemplate.GetSafeLink` to retrieve the pure URL path.

Example below is standard XSLT found in most templates in the default ItemStyle.xsl file.

```
<xsl:variable name="SafeLinkUrl">
  <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.GetSafeLink">
    <xsl:with-param name="UrlColumnName" select="'LinkUrl'"/>
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:variable>
```

Create your own variable with the below and you should be good to go.

```
<xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.GetSafeLink">
  <xsl:with-param name="UrlColumnName" select="'LinkUrl'"/>
</xsl:call-template>
```